# include() fails silently when called from an included file

Tags: php, include, include-path

I have a problem with including files on remote server (but on my local Windows PHP+Apache configuration it works fine...).

Problem occurs when I try to include file from included file like this:

Contents of index.php:

```
<?php

include("Dir1/File1.php");

?>
```

Contents of Dir1/File1.php:

```
<?php

include("File2.php");
include("File3.php");

echo("<p>File1 include done.</p>");

?>
```

Contents of Dir1/File2.php

```
<?php
echo("<p>File2 include done.</p>");
?>
```

Contents of Dir1/File3.php

```
<?php
echo("<p>File3 include done.</p>");
?>
```

File2.php and File3.php don't get evaluated, but when I change for example File2.php to File99.php (some non-existent file) I get standard warning that file doesn't exist.

But when I change contents of Dir1/File1.php to include files like this:

```
<?php

include("Dir1/File2.php");
include("Dir1/File3.php");

echo("<p>File1 include done.</p>");

?>
```

then files get evaluated...

Comment: Do you have access to the php.ini file on your remote server? Whats the `include_path` set to?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you don't have "." (current folder) in your include path. You should modify your php.ini file to add it. You can find out the value on your live and test server by doing

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: The value of remote include_path is:
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

Local version is:
.;C:\php5\pear

I don't think the problem is path because PHP knows where the include file is (because it throws warning if I change the include file to some non-existent file). I don't know whe if PHP can find file it does not evaluate it...

Comment: @Stazh, Perhaps you have blank files named File2.php and File3.php in the same dir as File1.php. Do "locate File2.php" from the Linux command line, and see if there are multiple copies of this file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full path include instead:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/Dir1/File3.php");
```

Comment: When I use full path it works fine, but I have a lot of files to change then... It's too much work. And on the other hand why it works just fine on my local configuration and on every other remote server I've used so far. The problem is obviously that particular remote server.

Answer (score 0):

this works every time for me:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/File3.php'); ?>
```